# Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, $a \in \mathbb{F}$ and set $p(x)=(x-a)^2$. Prove that $\mathbb{F}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, $a \in \mathbb{F}$ and set $p(x)=(x-a)^2$. Prove that $\mathbb{F}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is not a field.

I'm not sure where to start on this one. We were told to pick a nonzero class which is not invertible.

Comment: $[x-a]$ is certainly not zero. But when you square it...

Comment: It is reducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F},$ as $(x-a)^2=(x-a)(x-a).$ $\mathbb{F}[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle $ is a field if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $F[x]/(p)$ is a field iff $(p)$ is a maximal ideal of $F[x]$. Can you find $q\in F[x]$ such that $(q) \subsetneq (p) \subsetneq F[x]$?

Comment: I  highly doubt the OP would have to ask for help if they knew that more advanced result.

Comment: @BillDubuque they may just tell me and I'll elaborate or use some less advanced result.

Answer (score 0):

The thought process should be here that:
$$k[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\text{ is a field}\iff \langle f(x)\rangle\text{ is maximal}\iff f(x)\text{ is irreducible}$$
So, as $f(x)$ isn't irreducible (as $(x-a)^2 = (x-a)(x-a)$), we have that $k[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ isn't a field.